# Can I embed the google search API into my website so that it searches my database?

Tags: google-search, google-search-api

Off the bat: I'm not a developer so please excuse me if I sound dumb. I run a tech start up that provides a recruiting solution. This means that we have a database of client and candidate profiles. Clients search on the platform for skills and the search results are candidates that match those skills. I want to know if I can use the Google Search on my database so that when clients search they are returned with the best possible results (the current search function does not return the kind of results users expect in a Google era). If so what do I do / tell me developers?

Ive looked on the Google Search site but can't determine whether Google Search will be able to search only my websites back end data and return results based only on that info